# Error installing Node.js on my VPS (to get AjaxIM working in 'Guest' Mode)

Tags: ajax, node.js, vps

Error I get:

```
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
scons: *** [obj/release/api.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/colleg60/node-v0.4.6/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2): 
    {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

I am able to do the following but hit the snag above when I attempt to 'Make':

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.6.tar.gz
gunzip node-v0.4.6.tar.gz
tar -xf node-v0.4.6.tar
cd node-v0.4.6
./configure
make
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo make`. It appears you do not have the right to allocate memory.

This seems to be a server permission issue. We would need to know more about your specific VPS.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I tried that but it seems to get rejected by the server:
sudo make
colleg60 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

My vps is with inmotionhosting.com, 256mb dedicated memory

Comment: It defiantly sounds like an issue that needs to be resolved with tech support at inmotionhosting.

Comment: Ok I spoke to the support team and it is a permissions issue. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ok so I got the support for my VPS hosting to install the node but they sent me the following:
The following output is produced when running this file:

-bash-3.2# /usr/src/node-v0.4.6/node /home/colleg60/public_html/development/ajaxim/server/server.js

node.js:134
       throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
       ^

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'tcp'
   at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
   at Function._load (module.js:266:25)
   at require (module.js:348:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/colleg60/public_html/development/ajaxim/server/server.js:32:11)
   at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
   at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
   at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:423:10)
   at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)

However, the supplied 'Hello World' test file runs without an issue:

Comment: -bash-3.2# /usr/src/node-v0.4.6/node /usr/src/node-v0.4.6/test/message/hello_world.js
hello world

Comment: Ok So what needs to be changed then? The support team from my VPS followed the instructions directly from the site and got that error.

Comment: @JamesHickman it's your `server.js` file that has a bug in it.

Comment: Is that a part of the node.js package? It was downloaded directly from the site so not sure why there would be errors... What do I need to do to fix this and get it working?